# Six degrees of Kevin Bacon

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There are a couple other posts about degrees of Kevin Bacon, and the answers on those posts are similar to what I came up with myself before looking it up.  But it's evident that I'm still doing something wrong from the results I get and the way the performance of my query falls off as I increase the degree of separation from Kevin Bacon.

Here's my query to find all actors with one degree of Kevin Bacon:

```
match p=(:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[:ACTED_IN*..2]-(:Person) return p
```

If I understand correctly, that's equivalent to this:

```
match p=(:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person) return p
```

And indeed, both of these queries return the same number of rows.  But if I modify the first version of the query and increase the path length to 6 (i.e., three degrees of Kevin Bacon) it returns 978 rows.  There are only 133 Person nodes in the database, so I would expect it to return at most 133 rows.

My guess is that it's returning multiple paths to some of the Person nodes.  How do I tell it to return only the shortest path to each?  Basically, I want to perform a single depth-first or breadth-first search.  I think it might involve `WITH`, but I don't really understand how to use that yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two statements are not identical: `[:ACTED_IN*..2]` follows 1 to 2 relationships whereas the second statement forces exactly two relationships. (they return the same since there are no two Person nodes directly connected with a `:ACTED_IN` in your dataset.

You're right, you'll have multiple paths to the same end node. Cypher has a `shortestPath` function, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-match.html#_shortest_path.

If you want finer grained control e.g. depth-first vs. breadth-first you need to use e.g. Neo4j's [traversal API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal.html).

Comment: No matter what algorithm is used, wouldn't calling `shortestPath` several times with the same starting node duplicate a large amount of work?  I'm looking for a way to structure my query so the search tree created when finding all nodes within *n* relationships is reused to determine the shortest paths to each of those nodes.  If this is impossible in Cypher, can it be done using the REST traversal API?

Comment: As already mentioned I'd implement this using traversal API and expose this function using a unmanaged extension to make it accessible for your client code.

Comment: There are two traversal APIs that I'm aware of.  Can I do what I want using the REST traversal API, or only the Java traversal API?

Comment: I guess rest traversal is too limited, go with java traversal api